# Как найти количество элементов между объектами в структуре set?

Tags: c++, итераторы

Если нет, то почему нельзя сделать так:

```
auto k1 = v.lower_bound(x);
auto k2 = v.lower_bound(x - d);
long long count = k2 - k1;
```

Comment: А разве `set` гарантирует обход итератором в порядке возрастания ключа? Насколько я понимаю, определить число элементов "между" можно только полным обходом множества с подсчетом элементов, попадающих в интервал. Если, разумеется, не закладываться на конкретную реализацию.

Comment: Итератор этого контейнера является однонаправленным.   Разницу двух итераторов  возможно получать только при категории итераторов  произвольного доступа

Answer (score 0):

Вы не указали что из себя представляет `x` и `d`.  Ниже пример просто ответ на ваш вопрос, не опираясь на вашем примере

```
template <typename T>
long long dist(const T& x, const T& d,  std::set<T>& v)
{
    auto k1 = v.lower_bound(x);
    auto k2 = v.lower_bound(d); 
    //для того, чтобы k1 был ближе к началу v.begin()
    if (std::distance(v.begin(), k1) > std::distance(v.begin(), k2))
        std::swap(k1, k2);
    long long count = std::distance(k1, k2) - 1;
    return count;
}
```

auto `k1 и k2` являются однонаправленными итераторами, поэтому разницу между ними определять как для итераторов произвольного доступа, невозможно. Это делает  `std::distance`, которая вызывает подходящую перегруженную функцию_помощник. Если вы хотите, чтобы итератор указал на конец последовательности, при не найденном ключе, то вместо  `std::set<T>::lower_bound`  нужно использовать `std::set<T>::find`

Comment: @Abyx , потому что хотим найти количество елементов между  данными, а если функция и вернет  -1 , ничего не случится.  Просто узнаем, что  дистанция нулевая

Comment: Зачем 2 раза считать одно и тоже? `distance = std::distance(v.begin(), k1) - std::distance(v.begin(), k2)`

Comment: @Дмитрий Зиненко, вы что то путаете....

Comment: Ну по хорошему их нужно найти, сравнить и потом отнять, но если количество элементов влезает в long, то всё хорошо. На x64 влезает точно. На x32, нужно оооочень постараться.

Comment: @AR_Hovsepyan, почему по вашему `long distance = std::distance(v.begin(), k2) - std::distance(v.begin(), k1)` может не найти расстояние от k1 до k2. При условии, что ответ влазит в long. При это лишнего долгого std::distance(k1, k2) не нужно.

Comment: @Дмитрий Зиненко,  вопрос зыучит так:  "Если нет, то почему нельзя сделать так?...."  Я показал  почему нельзя делать так и логическую замену. Это обьяснение на коде, а не пример оптимального кода.  Ну а в контейнер, не  поместится столько элементов, чтобы количество  в  long не влез